# MYSQL INNER JOIN values from different tables in one row

Tags: mysql, case, inner-join

I have two tables.

**LoadSchedule**

| LoadNumber | LoadDate | Driver |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 15627 | 2021-08-10 | David |

**GpsTable**

| LoadNumber | LineNo | AddressCode | AddType |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15627 | 1 | A001 | C |
| 15627 | 2 | A002 | D |

I want the LoadNumber and LoadDate from the one table joined with the AddressCode from the other table as either SourceCode or DestinationCode (depending on the AddType being C or D). So the end result will be:

| LoadNumber | LoadDate | SourceCode | DestinationCode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15627 | 2021-08-10 | A001 | A002 |

What I have tried is the following:

```
select
DISTINCT ls.LoadNumber,
ls.LoadDate,
CASE WHEN gps.AddType = 'C' THEN gps.AddressCode END AS 'SourceGPSCode',
CASE WHEN gps.AddType = 'D' THEN gps.AddressCode END AS 'DestinationGPSCode'
FROM LoadSchedule AS ls INNER JOIN GpsTable as gps ON gps.LoadNumber = ls.LoadNumber
WHERE ls.LoadDate >= '2021-08-10'
```

The result is as follows

| LoadNumber | LoadDate | SourceCode | DestinationCode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15627 | 2021-08-10 | A001 |  |
| 15627 | 2021-08-10 |  | A002 |

I then try and get it on one row by using the GROUP BY function:

```
select
DISTINCT ls.LoadNumber,
ls.LoadDate,
CASE WHEN gps.AddType = 'C' THEN gps.AddressCode END AS 'SourceGPSCode',
CASE WHEN gps.AddType = 'D' THEN gps.AddressCode END AS 'DestinationGPSCode'
FROM LoadSchedule AS ls INNER JOIN GpsTable as gps ON gps.LoadNumber = ls.LoadNumber
WHERE ls.LoadDate >= '2021-08-10' GROUP BY ls.LoadNumber
```

But the result shows a (Null) for DestinationCode

| LoadNumber | LoadDate | SourceCode | DestinationCode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15627 | 2020-08-10 | A001 | (Null) |

Can you please help me to get the end result in one row as follows?

| LoadNumber | LoadDate | SourceCode | DestinationCode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15627 | 2021-08-10 | A001 | A002 |

Answer (score 0):

You need conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT ls.LoadNumber, ls.LoadDate,
       MAX(CASE WHEN gps.AddType = 'C' THEN gps.AddressCode END) AS SourceGPSCode,
       MAX(CASE WHEN gps.AddType = 'D' THEN gps.AddressCode END) AS DestinationGPSCode
FROM LoadSchedule AS ls INNER JOIN GpsTable AS gps 
ON gps.LoadNumber = ls.LoadNumber
WHERE ls.LoadDate >= '2021-08-10'
GROUP BY ls.LoadNumber, ls.LoadDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do by applying multiple left-joins

```
select distinct
      ls.LoadNumber,
      ls.LoadDate,
      src.AddressCode SourceGPSCode,
      dst.AddressCode DestinationGPSCode
   FROM 
      LoadSchedule ls 
         LEFT JOIN GpsTable src
            ON ls.LoadNumber = gps.LoadNumber
            AND src.AddType = 'C'
         LEFT JOIN GpsTable dst
            ON ls.LoadNumber = dst.LoadNumber
            AND dst.AddType = 'D'
   WHERE 
      ls.LoadDate >= '2021-08-10'
```

Now, if you have a single load that will have multiple source and/or distribution codes, this would create multiple rows representing as such.  But your context is otherwise unclear of that type of impact.  Thinking of GPS table, if you are dealing with trucking, for example, you may have one load that has multiple pickup sites, but also multiple drop-off sites as well.  What to do in those conditions.  You cant rely on just the first, max or last entry in either of those situations.  But only you can tell and provide feedback of such considerations.